# How to fix The model item passed into the dictionary is of type error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to run my first ASP.NET MVC application. I created a cotroller and view. Data is taken from Database. However, when project can run but when I try to navigate Customer page I get following error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication3.Models.Customer]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MvcApplication3.Models.Customer'.

I am bit confused here, as error says it has requesting model type.

Stack trace is

> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary
>   is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication3.Models.Customer]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MvcApplication3.Models.Customer'.]
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +585211
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary)
>   +371    System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +48    System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderViewPage(ViewContext
>   context, ViewPage page) +73
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +38
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +295    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
>   +89    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +102    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +47    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514812    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Here is my controller code.

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.NorthwindDataContext nwd = new Models.NorthwindDataContext();
            return View(nwd.Customers.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the view

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication3.Models.Customer>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptsSection" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Can anybody give me a hint to fix it?

Comment: your index action returns a list of customers. Is your view strongly typed to a list of customers or a single instance of customer ?

Comment: looks to me like you are passing List<Customer> but have @model customer, not list on the view

Comment: Just to see if this works, replace `nwd.Customers.ToList()` with `nwd.Customers.ToList().FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to pass a collection to a view that's designed for a single object.

change your view declaration to

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Customer>>`

Comment: Out of interest. In a usage where `RenderPartial` is being used, and the second parameter is `null`, does the executing partial then assume the model from the calling page?

Answer (score 3):

What exactly confuses you? In your aspx file you've defined the model as a customer, yet you pass a list instead to it.

Expected model:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication3.Models.Customer>
```

Your data:

```
return View(nwd.Customers.ToList());
```

Obviously a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

In your **related view** (i.e. the `.cshtml` file) look for the `@model` declaration: the `ActionResult` needs to return the right instance of the model class, e.g. if you have defined

```
@model Customer
```

then your ActionResult needs to be of type `Customer`.
You want to return a list, hence you need to define

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
```

in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was a problem of the model of the view. I had this code in my MVC project:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Author, AuthorViewModel>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dest = mapper.Map<Author, AuthorViewModel>(author);

        return View("Form", dest);
```

but the View Form.cshtml had the wrong model:

```
@model ORMVC.Models.Author
```

So I changed it to:

```
@model ORMVC.ViewModels.AuthorViewModel
```